# Angular FormGroup values null on event

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've got a simple `FormGroup`:

```
const formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    general: this.formBuilder.group({
        description: [job.description],
        country: [job.country],
        nextRun: [job.nextRun],
        lastRun: [job.lastRun],
        enabled: [job.enabled],
        tags: [this.jobTags]
    }),
    ...
})
```

Which I use to populate a `form`.
This `FormGroup` can be resetted to the original values:

```
this.formGroup.reset({
    general: {
       description: this.job.description,
       country: this.job.country,
       nextRun: this.job.nextRun,
       lastRun: this.job.lastRun,
       enabled: this.job.enabled,
       tags: this.jobTags
    },
    ...
})
```

And that happens via an event which is outputted from another `Component` via `EventEmitter`.

I've noticed that the entire `FormGroup` gets all its values set to `null` on the button press, before the `reset` method is called. This make the entire form "laggy" as values are basically cleared and re-inserted into the fields.

Is this something to expect? Or is it an error on my part?

**Solved:**

```
<button
    mat-stroked-button
    type="reset" <!-- Must be removed -->
    (click)="restorePressed.emit()"
>
    <mat-icon>restore</mat-icon>
    Restore
</button>
```

As you can see the button was marked as `type="reset"`. As simple as that.

Comment: We would need to see a bit more code in regards to this button press?

Comment: why do you have nested FormGroup instance ?

Comment: @JamieRees solved. See the updated question, at the bottom. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Florian what do you mean?

Comment: @LppEdd `reset` or `patchValue`?

Comment: @Abhishek I think in this case `reset` is more appropriate, as it clears the validators.

Comment: @LppEdd glad my question prompted you to look! I had a feeling it was going to be something like that.

Comment: your `formGroup`variable is a `FormGroup` instance, and your `general` variable is also a `FormGroup` instance. Is there any specific reason why you use FormGroup inside FormGroup ?

Comment: @JamieRees this is something I've written two months ago, it was the last thing I would have thought of. Thanks again!

Comment: @Florian Because I pass inner `FormGroup`(s) around to other components